# How to export multiple csv files at once

Tags: php

This exports one file with 2 rows in it. How can export 2 files each with one row in it?

```
<?php
$list = array (
  array("Peter", "Griffin" ,"Oslo", "Norway"),
  array("Glenn", "Quagmire", "Oslo", "Norway")
);

$file = fopen("contacts.csv","w");

foreach ($list as $line) {
  fputcsv($file, $line);
}

fclose($file);
?>
```

I tried this:

```
$list = array (
  array("Peter", "Griffin" ,"Oslo", "Norway"),
  array("Glenn", "Quagmire", "Oslo", "Norway")
);

$file = fopen('php://output', 'w');

$i = 1;
foreach ($list as $line) {
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $i . 'wp.csv"');
  fputcsv($file, $line);
  fclose($file);
  $i++;
}
```

But it only downloads one file. At least it only has the one row in it though.

I found this example. Even though it creates 2 separate csv files, the data is identical in each file instead of each file containing an individual record.

```
// some data to be used in the csv files
$headers = array('id', 'name', 'age', 'species');
$records = array(
    array('1', 'gise', '4', 'cat'),
    array('2', 'hek2mgl', '36', 'human')
);

// create your zip file
$zipname = 'file.zip';
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip->open($zipname, ZipArchive::CREATE);

// loop to create 3 csv files
for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {

    // create a temporary file
    $fd = fopen('php://temp/maxmemory:1048576', 'w');
    if (false === $fd) {
        die('Failed to create temporary file');
    }

    // write the data to csv
    fputcsv($fd, $headers);
    foreach($records as $record) {
        fputcsv($fd, $record);
    }

    // return to the start of the stream
    rewind($fd);

    // add the in-memory file to the archive, giving a name
    $zip->addFromString('file-'.$i.'.csv', stream_get_contents($fd) );
    //close the file
    fclose($fd);
}
// close the archive
$zip->close();


header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$zipname);
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zipname));
readfile($zipname);

// remove the zip archive
// you could also use the temp file method above for this.
unlink($zipname);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only put one "file" into an HTTP response.

If you want to generate multiple CSV files then you'll need to get more exotic. You could generate a HTML document of links to URLs that each generate a CSV file, or you could generate a zip file containing the CSV files.

Answer (score 0):

Just make a new File and use it like this

`$file2 = fopen("contacts2.csv", "w");
 fputcsv($file2, $list[1]);`

You always write in the same file here, because you are refering to $file

> fputcsv($file, $list[1]);

Comment: What if the values are dynamic? It won't always be 2 records ie: data could be coming from database and number of records unknown.

Comment: You can have a list of files or if you don't have predefined files, you can create a file in the foreach.

And you can create a $counter for giving different names. Something like

`$counter = 1;

foreach ($list as $line) {
 $newFile = fopen("contacts{$counter}".csv","w");
 fputcsv($newFile, $line);
 $counter++;
 fclose($newFile);
}`

Better would be a classic for($int i = 0; i<$list.length; i++), because you would have here a counter in the loop. And not outside the scope